# Causes of knee pain

Tags: discussion

Various answers to my question about recovery time, "[How much rest (tendon or ligament), for a novice?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/how-much-rest-tendon-or-ligament-for-a-novice)
", include information about the **causes** of knee pain, and how to prevent or avoid it.

I don't know whether to move that 'other' information into a separate question (perhaps CW). I'm not even sure if I want to; but if you want to (or if you want to edit the original question, or the question title, or the tags), please feel welcome to.

Perhaps there could be a new CW topic (e.g. "Several causes of knee pain") with many possible answers (too many days or too many hours per day; pre-existing condition; seat height; too cold; cleats in the wrong place; low RPM; ...?).

Comment: What does the pain in lower back mean? What does the fluctuating pain in upper back mean? How does my body react to adverse effects like stressful touring? Why did I get an abrupt pain in the evening? Can I trust my sensory system in x? Is it better to have regular pauses even if I don't feel any tired? How does pain differ between age? ... this topic is huge, break it into parts. Ask more. I know it is hard and requires a lot of research but that is to do it, try to focus on narrower topic about things which seem uncertain. I was about to fix some things but I ma puzzled by question.

Answer (score 3):

@ChrisW -

I have reservations about a community wiki on knee pain. The knee is a complex joint and there are quite a few causes of knee pain. And also, various solutions.

At the simplest, a cyclist may merely need to adjust the seat or cleat position. This sort of thing is probably ok for a "Cycling Knee Pain" wiki.

However, knee pain can be difficult to figure out. The pain can be anterior, posterior, lateral, or medial. And, the type of knee pain will vary as well.

Anecdotally, an acquaintance was suffering lateral knee pain. He diagnosed himself on a web forum with ITBS. And treated himself for that. It got worse, and it turns out, he had a lateral meniscus tear...and ultimately needed surgery.

A knee pain wiki could be possible with some strong caveats.

Comment: The fact that it has several causes/fixes is what would make it a good wiki topic. I agree though that the forum might not want any specifically-medical topics. FWIW I think my problem is/was fixed by some combination of a) getting my doctor to look at it and tell me it's alright now b) resting for nearly a week c) moving the cleats on my shoe d) not pushing so hard e) more practice f) moving the bike lock away from its previous position which was forcing my left knee away from the frame g) wearing knee supports/warmers.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't separate out the information on the cause of knee pain from this thread. The cause and the remedy (which may simply be rest days and, I suspect, changing your saddle height) are interrelated. Unless I'm missing the point? Is it that the answers are too broad?

The solution to too-broad answers is to downvote them, or edit them so they're more focused.

I said this in the comments on the question, but your responses to posipet's answer (that are integrated with your question) make the question very hard to read and overcomplex. I strongly suggest moving those to multiple comments under the appropriate answer.

I don't suggest moving the "cause" information into another question; it'd only make it harder to follow.

Comment: Now that I know more about knee pain I see that it could be structured as CW: several (different) possible causes of knee pain, each with it's own (different) solution. The OP was all about rest and about my specific problem. People's answers were (helpfully, but off-topic) not only about rest but also hypothesising about the various possible causes.